# Interacting with Wikipedia's API: grabbing the content of the table present on a page

Tags: java, mysql, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

E.g.

1. Here is a link   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brad_Pitt_filmography
   which lists all the films of brad Pitt in table format.
   I want grab the table content.

Query-> http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Brad_Pitt_filmography&

what other parameters will come in the query ?

2. How can I store it in MySQL Database  using Java

Answer (score 2):

use "action=parse":

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=xml&prop=text&page=Brad_Pitt_filmography&section=1&contentformat=text/plain

you can change "prop" to text(html) or wikitext. for more info please check this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse